# How to find the modules or classes that include a module?

Tags: ruby

There is a good trick which helps to find inherited subclasses:

```
class SubClasses

  @@subclasses ||= []

  def self.inherited subclass
    @@subclasses << subclass
  end

  def self.subclasses
    @@subclasses
  end
end
```

Also, I found it useful to find modules included in child classes with `Foo.included_modules`.

But it is unavailable on `Module`. How I can fetch all classes which include the module? Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

Solved!

[Getting a list of classes that include a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917857/getting-a-list-of-classes-that-include-a-module)

Comment: I almost marked this question as a duplicate of the one you linked to, but that question starts with the answer to yours and goes on to something more complicated, so yours does a better job of just asking what's in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To monitor when a module is included in another module or a class, use the `included` hook:

```
module Parent
  class << self
    attr_reader :includers
  end

  def self.included(base)
    @includers ||= []
    @includers << base.name
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! It is much more right and fast way, than look throw all `ObjectSpace` :)
So now I know 2 ways

Comment: Mike, Ruby wouldn't work up a sweat looking through all the classes. For Ruby 2.3.0, `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a.size #=> 533`.  btw, I like the answer you are referring to at the link. Good answer, @Dave.